# How to sort dates if these are strings in custom field?

Tags: php

I have a series of posts, with dates in a custom fields like:

```
02/12/1978 

01/11/1987
```

These are actual strings and not dates.

Then I run the following, where I try to sort by dates, and I also attach each dates post id, in order them to run the posts ordered:

```
    $dateOrdered = [];
    while ( $queryPosts->have_posts() ) : $queryPosts->the_post();
        $id = $post->ID;
        $date = usp_get_meta(false, 'usp-custom-80');
        array_push($postOrdered, $id);
        $dateOrdered[] = array("date"=>$date, "id"=>$id);
    endwhile;
endif;

function custom_sort_dt($b, $a) {
    return strtotime($a['date']) - strtotime($b['date']);
}
usort($dateOrdered, "custom_sort_dt");

$dateOrdered = implode(',', array_column($dateOrdered, 'id'));
```

But that is showing dates not ordered.

Comment: What is that while syntax?

Comment: `custom_sort_dt($b, $a)` should be `custom_sort_dt($a, $b)`

Comment: According to [this](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) your date format is not recognized by `strtotime`

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy that is just some wordpress function to handle the loop

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy that's valid. Not common, but valid. See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca how could I convert it dynamically in something recognizable?

Comment: If the first number is a day and the second is a month, you can just swap `.` for `/`

Comment: Dynamically? You mean there are more than one format?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca would be able to provide a code example based on the code above please?

Comment: @Andreas nope, I mean to convert those strings into dates in order to make them valid and apply the ordering logic

Comment: @rob.m `str_replace('/', '.', $a['date'])` should do the trick

Comment: tried this but not ordered `function custom_sort_dt($a, $b) {
          return str_replace('/', '.', $a['date']) - str_replace('/', '.', $a['date']);
      }` @FedericoklezCulloca

Comment: you're comparing `$a` with itself?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca LOL hang on, i try again, thanks

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca nothing, still not ordered       function custom_sort_dt($a, $b) {
          return str_replace('/', '.', $a['date']) - str_replace('/', '.', $b['date']);
      }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you have some type of "Post" class like

```
class Post {
    public $date;
}
```

and you save them in an array named `$posts`, you can execute following code:

```
$dates =  array_map(function($p) { return DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/yy', $p->date)->getTimestamp(); }, $posts);
asort($dates);
```

and have a sorted $dates array. the values are unix-timestamps.

**Edit**:

the dates are in the format dd-mm-yyyy, so we need to use 'd-m-yy'.

We also need to fully qualify DateTime by adding a \ in front of it.

```
$postOrdered[] = [];
while ($queryPosts->have_posts()) {
    $queryPosts->the_post(); 
    $id = get_the_ID(); 
    $postOrdered[$id] = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-yy', usp_get_meta(false,'usp-custom-80'))->getTimestamp();
}

asort($postOrdered);
$ids = array_keys($postOrdered)
```

to echo the post content then use

```
foreach($postOrdered as $id=>$date) { 
    echo get_post($id)->post_content . '<br />'; 
}
```

Comment: in the loop, I am setting $date, $date = usp_get_meta(false, 'usp-custom-80');. I guess I need to convert that into a date format from there. how tho?

Comment: @rob.m this part does that `DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/yy', $p->date)`

Comment: @rob.m does `usp_get_meta` return the date? then you need to adapt the code as @Andreas said `DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/yy', usp_get_meta(false,'usp-custom-80')`

Comment: @Isitar that lines breaks

Comment: ok thanks, now i believe it is converting it as a date but not ordering       $id = $post->ID; 
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/yy', usp_get_meta(false,'usp-custom-80'));
              array_push($postOrdered, $id);
              $dateOrdered[] = array("date"=>$date, "id"=>$id);
          endwhile;
      endif;
      function custom_sort_dt($a, $b) {
          return strtotime($a['date']) - strtotime($b['date']);
      }
      usort($dateOrdered, "custom_sort_dt");
      $dateOrdered = implode(',', array_column($dateOrdered, 'id'));